# dynamic pagination within dynamic page

Tags: php

I am trying to make a pagination within a dynamic page, but it will bring me back to the index page, it will send me back to site/p=index

index.php

```
<?php

include('navbar.php');

$pages_dir = 'includes';

if(!empty($_GET['p'])) {

$pages = scandir($pages_dir, 0);
unset($pages[0], $pages[1]);

$p = $_GET['p'];

if(in_array($p.'.inc.php', $pages)) {
    include($pages_dir.'/'.$p.'.inc.php');  

}

else 
    {
    echo    '<div id="content"> 
                <h2>Error</h2>
                Page not found!
            </div>';                
            include('side.php');                    
    }

} else {
    include($pages_dir.'/main.inc.php');
}

    include('footer.php');

?>
```

navbar.php

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
       <li class="highlight"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>  
       <li><a href="index.php?p=news">News</a></li> 
       <li><a href="index.php?p=features">Features</a></li>
       <li><a href="index.php?p=column">Column</a></li>
    </ul>
 <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

pagination functions

pagination.php

```
<?php



   function pagination($query, $per_page = 10,$page = 1, $url = '?'){        
        $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as `num` FROM {$query}";
        $row = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
        $total = $row['num'];
        $adjacents = "2"; 

        $page = ($page == 0 ? 1 : $page);  
        $start = ($page - 1) * $per_page;                               

        $prev = $page - 1;                          
        $next = $page + 1;
        $lastpage = ceil($total/$per_page);
        $lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;

        $pagination = "";
        if($lastpage > 1)
        {   
            $pagination .= "<ul class='pagination'>";
                    $pagination .= "<li class='details'>Page $page of $lastpage</li>";
            if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2))
            {   
                for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>$counter</a></li>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$counter'>$counter</a></li>";                    
                }
            }
            elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2))
            {
                if($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 2))        
                {
                    for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)
                    {
                        if ($counter == $page)
                            $pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>$counter</a></li>";
                        else
                            $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$counter'>$counter</a></li>";                    
                    }
                    $pagination.= "<li class='dot'>...</li>";
                    $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$lpm1'>$lpm1</a></li>";
                    $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$lastpage'>$lastpage</a></li>";      
                }
                elseif($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents * 2))
                {
                    $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=1'>1</a></li>";
                    $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=2'>2</a></li>";
                    $pagination.= "<li class='dot'>...</li>";
                    for ($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++)
                    {
                        if ($counter == $page)
                            $pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>$counter</a></li>";
                        else
                            $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$counter'>$counter</a></li>";                    
                    }
                    $pagination.= "<li class='dot'>..</li>";
                    $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$lpm1'>$lpm1</a></li>";
                    $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$lastpage'>$lastpage</a></li>";      
                }
                else
                {
                    $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=1'>1</a></li>";
                    $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=2'>2</a></li>";
                    $pagination.= "<li class='dot'>..</li>";
                    for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
                    {
                        if ($counter == $page)
                            $pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>$counter</a></li>";
                        else
                            $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$counter'>$counter</a></li>";                    
                    }
                }
            }

            if ($page < $counter - 1){ 
                $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$next'>Next</a></li>";
                $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$lastpage'>Last</a></li>";
            }else{
                $pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>Next</a></li>";
                $pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>Last</a></li>";
            }
            $pagination.= "</ul>\n";        
        }


        return $pagination;
    } 
?>
```

can anyone help me with the function pagination $url='?'

Comment: Do you mean that , your page is dynamic, and you wish to have a pagination for it? If so, check out this tutorial: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-paginate-data-with-php/

Comment: There's an excellent video tutorial on how to do it here: youtube.com/phpapplied